# How to save data to a file in Java without using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

How do I save my collection "database" to a file and then read it without having to use Hibernate?

I save it with this code:

```
ObjectOutputStream save = null;

try{
    save = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("data.txt"));
    save.writeObject(database);
    return true;
}catch(IOException e){
    System.err.println("I/O error!");
    return false;
}finally{
    save.close();
}
```

Then I read the file with this code:

```
File file = new File("data.txt");
if(!(file.exists()))
    save();
ObjectInputStream read = null;

try{
    read = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("data.txt"));
    database =  (Set<Allincomes>) read.readObject();
    return true;
}catch(IOException e){
    System.err.println("I/O error!");
    return false;
}catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
    System.err.println("Class not found!");
    return false;
}finally{
    read.close();
}
```

But my teacher said not to use Hibernate since the file that I save all the data to is as he said "unreadable".

Comment: there is no hibernate in your code

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid serialising your objects as it's only meant for short term storage.  Either write your own routines to write the content based on the type of objects or consider using something like java [JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) or even JSON (look up GSON) which will provide you means by which you can serialise your objects in a more stable state for long term storage.